# Change column name when retrieving data from mysql database in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

**My problem background :**

I have spatial point field in my mysql database called location

**What i want to achieve :**

I want to retrieve this spatial point

**What is the problem :**

When i retrieve it was be like : \u0000\u0000\u0000

**How i solved it:**

```
DB::table('stores')->select( DB::Raw('ST_X(location)'),DB::Raw('ST_Y(location)'))
```

**Ok ,Now what is the issue:**

The fields is retrieved like this "ST_Y(location)": 30

**Ok ,Now what i want to achieve :**

I want to change key name to be something like "latitude": 30,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `as` inside the `DB::raw` expressions, it will alias it.

```
DB::table('stores')
    ->select(DB::Raw('ST_X(location) as longitude'), DB::Raw('ST_Y(location) as latitude'))
    ->get()
```

Comment: Thanks it solved now, I will accept your answer after 9 minutes as stackoverflow say to me :'D